# How I can extrude down?

Tags: modeling, mesh, extrude

I'm new to Blender and I  have used the extrude tool. But somehow it doesn't go down, like creating a "void", it's like it is copying the same face again.

You can see the circle was extruded, but just don't go down.

I can't insert more images, but I want to get this result on [**10:30** on this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=98FkRIbihyQ&t=617s)

[image]

Comment: Not sure why that is happening - it shouldn't. Instead of using the extrude tool, try using the hotkeys - E (extrude), followed by the axis (Z) and then move your mouse to change the level of the surface. Does this make any difference?

Comment: It's strange, because when I create a new project, it just work normal as it should. I think that maybe cause some sort of configuration or I have changed the proprieties since creation.
And remembering this is a copy from other object. I just do it for training.

Answer (score 5):

..Hard to reverse-engineer what you've done, but there are a couple of clues in your picture:

- The edges in the top surface look a little thick? There are possibly some doubled faces / vertices there. Try <kbd>X</kbd> deleting, or <kbd>H</kbd> hiding some of the faces, to see if there are more hidden underneath. It's a feature of Blender's extrude, that if you cancel by right-clicking, you don't cancel the *extrusion*. You cancel the *move*, so the generated faces remain, exactly over the originals.
- The Gizmo indicates that *something* is being operated on, halfway down the bottle. <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> go into X-Ray mode, and see if there's a face there, which is the one being extruded, out of sight.

Comment: Thank you. I did it.
But I have created the object all over again. Somehow I I have created duplicated face and  I don't know how.
That's strange...

Comment: @MatheusFreitas If you start an extrusion and right click to cancel it, you're actually confirming an extrusion with an offset of 0 from the original geometry. I used to double faces by doing this all the time until I realized that right clicking didn't undo the extrusion like I thought.

Comment: @ChrisHayes .. I used to think this was a problem in the interface to extrude/inset.. but once you're used to it, it's actually useful. Like so much in Blender, IMO.  a bit less 'convenience', a bit more learning, makes a better tool.